# text not showing in my bootstrap textarea

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new to Bootstrap and CSS, so please excuse the probable immaturity of my question.

Ok, so here goes:

**Context**:
I'm using bootstrap and the [Grayscale theme] for a simple tool I'm building to help my students use coursera more effectively.

I have the following snippet of code:

```
<div>
  <form class="form-inline">            
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-4">
          <input type="text" class="from-control" placeholder="Enter the link to your course">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Download Videos</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>         
  </form>
</div>
```

**Problems:**

1. The text entered in the textbox is not visible. I made sure text is actually entered in the box (by copy/pasting it to an editor) and I have not changed the default text color.
2. I can't seem to change the size of the text area. I've used `col-xs-1`, `col-xs-2`, and many more variations. It always takes the default size. The only thing that changes is the position of the textbox and button on the page. Do you know why that happens?

I would really appreciate your help! I've looked at some similar questions on the topic, but couldn't figure this out.

Many thanks!

Raf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class for the textbox should be `form-control`, not `from-control`. Change that and try again?

EDIT: There is no such class as `col-xl-4` in Bootstrap. Use `col-xs-4` or `col-lg-4`.

Comment: ah, I'm an idiot!
Thank you so much for your quick help :)

So, that resolved the text-invisibility issue. Do you know how I can change the size of the box by any chance? or why's it's not changing with above variations?

Comment: Easy mistake to make :) Also take a look at your classes, I don't think there's a "col-xl-4" class

Comment: Ok, so the first problem was resolved (thanks to you :)  

RE the second one, this is what I got; posted links to the screenshots for your review:

With all the following variations, the textbox and button are aligned left on the page and split into 2 rows:
col-lg-1, col-lg-2, col-lg-3, col-md-1, col-md-2, col-lg-3: 
http://i.imgur.com/K7WmRkC.jpg

And the following: textbox & button aligned to the middle of the page (as I want it to be) and in 1 row, howver, the size still doesn't change.
col-md-4, col-lg-4, no formatting (<!--<div class="col-md-3"> </div> -->)
http://i.imgur.com/7mhPwOw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

@GertV is correct above in sying that you should be using `form-control` and that `col-xl` classes do not exist. The reason you cannot see the textarea though is that you have not declared its width.

Try this:

```
<div>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" style="width: 300px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the link to your course">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Download Videos</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I added the col-span, but I still get the same result; posted the links to the screenshots above if it helps?